# Registered theme with xml import not use setted default layout template

Tags: websphere-portal

I am using WebSphere 8.0. In my imported xml for theme registration I set com.ibm.portal.layout.template.href to existed layout 1Row2ColumnUnequal.

```
<parameter name="com.ibm.portal.layout.template.href" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[war:ErkcThemeStatic/themes/ErkcTheme/layout-templates/1Row2ColumnUnequal/]]></parameter>
```

But after applying theme default layout template sets to 1Column. Here is the full xml.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request type="update" version="8.0.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="PortalConfig_8.0.0.xsd">
    <portal action="locate">

        <skin action="update" active="true" default="false" domain="rel" objectid="ErkcDefault.Skin" uniquename="ErkcDefault.Skin" resourceroot="ErkcDefault.Skin" context-root="/ErkcThemeStatic" type="default">
            <localedata locale="en">
                <title>Erkc Default Skin</title>
            </localedata>
            <parameter name="com.ibm.portal.skintype" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[template]]></parameter>

            <parameter name="com.ibm.portal.skin.template.ref" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[res:/ErkcThemeStatic/skins/ErkcDefaultSkin/]]></parameter>
            <parameter name="com.ibm.portal.skin.template.file.name.html" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[skin.html]]></parameter>
        </skin>

        <skin action="update" active="true" default="false" domain="rel" objectid="Erkc.Hide" uniquename="Erkc.Hide" resourceroot="Erkc.Hide" context-root="/ErkcThemeStatic" type="default">
            <localedata locale="en">
                <title>Erkc Hide Skin</title>
            </localedata>

            <parameter name="com.ibm.portal.skintype" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[template]]></parameter>
            <parameter name="com.ibm.portal.skin.template.ref" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[res:/ErkcThemeStatic/skins/ErkcHideSkin/]]></parameter>
            <parameter name="com.ibm.portal.skin.template.file.name.html" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[skin.html]]></parameter>
        </skin>

        <skin action="locate" domain="rel" objectid="ErkcDefault.Skin.objectID" uniquename="ErkcDefault.Skin"/>
        <skin action="locate" domain="rel" objectid="Erkc.Hide.objectID" uniquename="Erkc.Hide"/>

        <theme action="update" active="true" context-root="/ErkcThemeDynamic" default="false" defaultskinref="ErkcDefault.Skin.objectID" domain="rel" resourceroot="dynamicSpots" uniquename="Erkc.Theme">
            <localedata locale="en">
                <title>Erkc Theme</title>
            </localedata>

            <allowed-skin skin="ErkcDefault.Skin.objectID" update="set" />
            <allowed-skin skin="Erkc.Hide.objectID" update="set" />

            <parameter name="com.ibm.portal.theme.dnd.sources" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[ibmDndColumn:com.ibm.pb.dnd.layout.LayoutColumnSource:vertical,ibmDndRow:com.ibm.pb.dnd.layout.LayoutRowSource:horizontal]]></parameter>
            <parameter name="com.ibm.portal.theme.aggregationmodes" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[ssa]]></parameter>
            <parameter name="com.ibm.portal.layout.template.href" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[war:ErkcThemeStatic/themes/ErkcTheme/layout-templates/1Row2ColumnUnequal/]]></parameter>
            <parameter name="com.ibm.portal.theme.template.ref" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[war:ErkcThemeStatic/themes/ErkcTheme/]]></parameter>
            <parameter name="resourceaggregation.profile" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[profiles/profile_deferred.json]]></parameter>
            <parameter name="com.ibm.portal.theme.hasBaseURL" type="string" update="set"><![CDATA[true]]></parameter>
        </theme>

    </portal>
</request>
```

Answer (score 0):

your xmlaccess shows you are on 8000 portal I would recommend at LEAST getting to 8001 as there were many defects around in this in 8000